# Proving that $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{t} n^{2r+1}}{\sum_{n=1}^{t} n}$ is an integer

Tags: calculus, summation, integers

I am trying to prove that $$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{t} n^{2r+1}}{\sum_{n=1}^{t} n}$$ is an integer for $r,t\geq 1$.

I have managed to show this for $r=1$ and $r=2$ but I don't know where to go from here. How do I prove this for all $t$ and $r$?

Thank you!

Comment: try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials

Comment: @TStancek thank you!